# Python eval(repr(object)) - invalid syntax

Tags: python, class, repr

I am messing around building a deck of cards. I have an issue where I have read that eval(repr(object)) should be equivalent to the object [stack overflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python).

I implemented two classes for my cards, a Card class and a Deck class. Each has a repr method in which I attempted to keep as close to the syntax of actually creating the object. Code for init and repr of Card and Deck:

```
class Card(object):

    def __init__(self, num, suit):
        self.__num = num
        self.__suit = suit

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{!r}({!r},{!r})".format(self.__class__, self.__num, self.__suit)

class Deck(object):

    def __init__(self, cards=None):
        if not cards:
            self.__cards = {"diamonds":[], "hearts":[], "spades":[], "clubs":[]}
        else:
            self.__cards = cards

    def __repr__(self):
         return "{!r}({!r})".format(self.__class__, self.__dict__)
```

and here is the error:

```
print(eval(repr(self.deck.deck)))
File "<string>", line 1
{'hearts': [<class 'cards.Card'>(1,'hearts'), <class 'cards.Card'>(2,'hearts'), <class 'cards.Card'>(3,'hearts'), <class 'cards.Card'>(4,'hearts'), <class 'cards.Card'>(5,'hearts')], 'clubs': [<class 'cards.Card'>(1,'clubs'), <class 'cards.Card'>(2,'clubs'), <class 'cards.Card'>(3,'clubs'), <class 'cards.Card'>(4,'clubs'), <class 'cards.Card'>(5,'clubs')], 'spades': [<class 'cards.Card'>(1,'spades'), <class 'cards.Card'>(2,'spades'), <class 'cards.Card'>(3,'spades'), <class 'cards.Card'>(4,'spades'), <class 'cards.Card'>(5,'spades')], 'diamonds': [<class 'cards.Card'>(1,'diamonds'), <class 'cards.Card'>(2,'diamonds'), <class 'cards.Card'>(3,'diamonds'), <class 'cards.Card'>(4,'diamonds'), <class 'cards.Card'>(5,'diamonds')]}
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am simply guessing that it is because of how the Card class is represented. I attempted substituting {!r} for {!s} but it didn't change it. I was considering just hard coding the fact that it is of the class Card in there, but I was hoping there would be some specific way I am meant to do it.

To solve:
Just needed to add `.__name__` after the `self.__class__` and use {!s} (so as to remove the quotes) rather that {!r}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see, your `repr` is not at all the form used to create the object.  It is `<class 'cards.Card'>(1,'hearts')`, not `Card(1, 'hearts')`.  One way to fix this would be to use `self.__class__.__name__` in your `__repr__` instead of just `self.__class__`.

However, why are you doing this?  Are you just using `eval(repr(...))` to test that the repr is good?  There are better ways to create a duplicate of an instance than using `eval(repr(...))`.

Comment: Yes, it was my intent to include it in my unit tests just as a test for the repr - would there be a more appropriate method of doing this? 

Thank you. :)

Comment: It seems to me that `def copy(self): return eval(repr(self))` is a great way to implement a method for creating the duplicate of an instance. What's wrong with that, or what are the "better ways"?

Answer (score 2):

Don't repr the class itself, use its name.

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "{}({!r},{!r})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.__num, self.__suit)
```

It should then look like what it looks like in source code.